# How to create a Dockerfile for Nextjs and graphql?

Tags: docker, next.js

I tried to deploy my Nextjs project to Heroku via Docker, so i follow docs on internet,then i get a Dockerfile like this

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
# COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
# RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
RUN npm ci

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
# RUN yarn build && yarn install --production --ignore-scripts --prefer-offline
RUN npm run build && npm install --production --ignore-scripts --prefer-offline

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

# You only need to copy next.config.js if you are NOT using the default configuration
# COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry.
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

# CMD ["yarn", "start"]
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

and .dockerignore

```
node_modules
.next
```

But i get this error when building

```
 ERROR [runner 5/8] COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
```

I think this error right because i don't see public folder in my project, maybe my project missing it

Then i go to learn basic about docker, i dont know so much , but i can create a simple Dockerfile like this

```
FROM node

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./


RUN npm install

COPY . .

# RUN npm run build

# ENV NODE_ENV=production

EXPOSE 3000
USER node

CMD [ "npm","run","dev"]
```

with .dockerignore above,I test it with dev enviroment, if it can run I'll edit to production, I run my project by command

```
docker run -it -p 3000:3000 --name run-my-client my-client
```

But i get this error

```
[Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/src/app/.next/build-manifest.json'] {
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'unlink',
  path: '/usr/src/app/.next/build-manifest.json'
}
```

I still see build-manifest.json file in .next folder, but i don't know why this error is appear.Am i missing something and How can i fix it?